# Indoor Location Positioning using 3 Wi-Fi Access Points

Tags: android, rssi, user-location

I wanted to ask, is it possible to locate user's position in a building using 3 Wi-Fi Access Points?

According to my research, it is possible, but with those 3 Wi-Fi AP, I also need to use RSSI to make it work. my question, how do I merge, or implement these 2 features as one?

Comment: You also need to have good position data on the access point positions, ideally also on their orientation and signal strength.

Comment: You probably need to know what is in the area you want to map too - for example, if there's a big concrete wall between two AP's, the RSSI values could vary greatly on either side.

Answer (score 1):

you have to calculate the time between the APs. If you have something that will affect the signal in the middle you need one more AP to cover all points (considering you are doing it in a square room). then to map the place you just have to do something like touchscreen calibration to lock the APs position. Use the first 3 APs that are at the same condition, low signal or high signal.

Answer (score 0):

this project maybe can help you.

http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring11/group02/index.html

Good luck...